# Parse HTTP header of Google Cloud Messaging notification

Tags: android, http, parsing, google-cloud-messaging

Hello Everyone I have made an app that gets notification from file uploaded to certain URL and also i am able to download that file from the same URL.
I can get information gcm response using

```
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    //String msg = intent.getStringExtra("message");
    String msg = intent.getStringExtra("message");
```

And I know that if it was my HttpGet request I could get the HTTP header information using :

```
    get all headers
    Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
    for (Header header : headers) {
        System.out.println("Key : " + header.getName()
                + " ,Value : " + header.getValue());
    }

    //get header by 'key'
    String server = response.getFirstHeader("Server").getValue();
```

But if i download the file typing URL in chrome Browser it displays the file Name in Notification and I want to extract file name from the HTTP header of the GCM and i want to use it as one parameter for downloading the file from URL as file names are change as i upload another file to URL.
I don't want to pass file name as I have to pass other information for notification purpose,

So shortly how can I parse HTTP header of Google Cloud Messaging Bundle that we get from GCM  Server in android?

Comment: didn't understand, what file name?

Comment: file name of the file to download after clicking in the notification...

Comment: Your problem is interesting.. but not able to understand what you are trying to achieve. So you want the notification on the Android device when some one downloads the file from the browser... Is that correct? Please edit the post to help understand your implementation...